# QGIS - converting categorical raster to polygon includes raster boundary

Tags: qgis, gdal-polygonize

I am using the QGIS Raster Convert Raster to Polygon tool (which calls gdal_polygonize under the hood), to convert a raster in a netcdf file to a polygon. The raster is a binary mask. The issue is that the conversion results in an additional polygon of a "frame" of the raster extents.

How do I not include this frame in the vector conversion?

[image: polygonized raster with outline]

Comment: have you tried setting the background pixel value as the no data value?

Comment: This worked! All I had to do was set all unwanted values in my binary mask to NaN in my netcdf and the tool worked perfectly! Thanks for your help.